# "Current time" outputs as zero

Tags: awk

I am trying to input to`file2` from `file1` so that each line in `file2` is the first field of each `file1` line, followed by a space and the current time.

E.g.

```
IN-X_4096_20140802_121306_007 `random text`
IN-X_4096_20140802_133431_012 `random text`
IN-A_6046_20130613_165426 `random text`
IN-A_6046_20130613_165426 `random text`
IN-X_4096_20140802_133431_014 `random text`
```

becomes

```
IN-X_4096_20140802_121306_007 14:24:32
IN-X_4096_20140802_133431_012 14:24:32
IN-A_6046_20130613_165426 14:24:32
IN-A_6046_20130613_165426 14:24:32
IN-X_4096_20140802_133431_014 14:24:32
```

But what I am getting is

```
IN-X_4096_20140802_121306_007 0
IN-X_4096_20140802_133431_012 0
IN-A_6046_20130613_165426 0
IN-A_6046_20130613_165426 0
IN-X_4096_20140802_133431_014 0
```

The code I am using is:

```
awk '{b=$1" "date +"%r"; print b >"file2.csv" }' file1.csv
```

The same thing happens when I use "%T"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it is not clear which behaviour you are expecting, but here are two Gnu awk solutions:

1. The computed date-time string has to be constant during the entire run of the command:

   ```
   awk 'BEGIN{t=strftime("%r")}{ print $1,t }' file1.csv > file2.csv
   ```
2. The computed date-time string has to be updated per line:

   ```
   awk '{ print $1,strftime("%r") }' file1.csv > file2.csv
   ```

Comment: Works great.  TYVM.

Comment: I should probably post a new question for this, but how would I set up the code so that what is sent into the CSV is two seperate fields, i.e one column for the $1 and another column for the time?

Comment: a space is fine as the FS.  In case it is relevant, only file 2 is CSV, file1 is not.

Comment: unfortunately this still results in the CSV file putting both fields in one cell, creating 1 column only.

Comment: I have done this, here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856676/awk-outputs-two-fields-into-a-csv-file-but-csv-file-places-both-fields-in-the-s

Answer (score 3):

Written like that, `date` is interpreted as a variable name. As it is unset, it evaluates to `""` or `0` depending on the context. The `+` operator after it means that it is evaluated in an arithmetic context, therefore it takes the value `0`.

To pass the value of `date +%r` to your awk script, use either of these approaches:

```
# the time when the script was run, doesn't change
awk -v time="$(date +%r)" '{ print time }' file1.csv

# the time when each record is read
awk '{ cmd = "date +%r"; cmd | getline time; print time; close(cmd) }' file1.csv
```

Comment: the explanation regarding the 0 was very helpful