# Awk outputs two fields into a CSV file, but CSV file places both fields in the same cell

Tags: csv, awk

This is a follow up question to [Awk: “Current time” outputs as zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854404/awk-current-time-outputs-as-zero/52854772?noredirect=1#comment92626727_52854772)

I am trying to send the first field in file1 and the current time, as two seperate fields, into a `.CSV` file so that `field1` will populate a different cell than `field2`.

E.g.in file one. a row looks like this:

```
IN-X_4096_20140802_121306_007 `random text`
```

[edit:] where in this particular row of file1, the 007 ends the first field, and 'random text' means numerous fields appear in the row along with the first field described above.

[edit:] I want that field 1 is taken from `file1` and becomes a cell in the `file2.CSV`.  So column 1 in file2.csv will always be field 1 from file 1.  The tricky part seems to be to make column 2 in file2.csv contain the time.

```
N-X_4096_20140802_121306_007 (cell in column A) 14:24:32 (cell in column B)
```

The code I am using is:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{ print $1 strftime(" %r")}' file1.jump > file2.csv
```

At the moment, this code results in the `.CSV` file placing the entire output into one cell, for each row, in file2.csv.  Is there a way to make the output go into seperate cells in the `.CSV`?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not really clear. Can you give a clear example of what your input is, and how it should look like? Eg. file 1 has lines like "A B C D" and I expect it to have the output like "A,14:24:32,B,C,D" or something like that.

Comment: It is also really good that you atomize your questions! Keep up the good work!

Comment: Change `$1 strftime(" %r")` to `$1, strftime("%r")`

Comment: @ZakS Was The solution of EdMorton Correct?

Comment: Dear @EdMorton -- it works, thank you.  Am I understanding correctly that since OFS=, sets the field operator to a "," -- it therefore outputs as two seperate fields?

Comment: @ZakS I have added a bit of information to my answer about your question to EdMorton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it seems that your actual question is:

> How does the `print` statement work and how is it affected by the variable `OFS`.

First of all, it is important that realize that the two most important concepts to [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) are *records* and *fields*.

The input which is fed into awk through various means (`stdin` or `getline`) is read *record* by *record* where each record is separated by a record separator which is defined by `RS`. Since `RS` is by default the <newline> character `\n`, a record is actually a line and thus awk processes default a file line-by-line.

When a record/line is read, awk will split the record in fields where each field is separated by the field separator `FS` (which can be a regular expression). By default, the field separator `FS` is set to be any sequence of <blank> characters. Which means that, by default, each field is a word. If you redefine `FS`, fields will be different. Eg.

```
Mooo, that sexy cow!
```

has 4 fields by default (`$1="Mooo,"`, `$2="that"`, `"$3="sexy"` and `$4="cow!"`) but if `FS=","` it only has 2 fields (`$1="Mooo"` and `$2=" that sexy cow!"`)

The above is all about input and how awk understands it, but also in **output** the concept of *records* and *fields* is known. And this is where the `print` statement comes in. The `print` statement allows you to print a record which is build of various fields. The output record separator `ORS`, by default a <newline> character `\n`, tells you how two records are separated and the output field separator `OFS`, by default a <space>  , tells you how the fields are separated. The print statement looks like

```
print arg1, arg2, ..., argn
```

and will print a record with `n` fields separated by `OFS` and ending with `ORS`.

> The print statement shall write the value of each expression argument onto the indicated output stream separated by the current output field separator (see variable `OFS` above), and terminated by the output record separator (see variable `ORS` above). All expression arguments shall be taken as strings, being converted if necessary; this conversion shall be as described in Expressions in awk, with the exception that the `printf` format in `OFMT` shall be used instead of the value in `CONVFMT`. An empty expression list shall stand for the whole input record (`$0`).
>
> **<sup>source: [POSIX Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sup>**

So now to answer the question. Your original line reads:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{ print $1 strftime(" %r")}' file1.jump > file2.csv
```

here `OFS` has no effect as print has only a single argument which reads `$1 strftime(" %r")` (note that the space between `$1` and `strftime` has no meaning and can be ignored, so both strings are concatenated. So what you want is this:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{ print $1, strftime("%r")}' file1.jump > file2.csv
```

---

**original (wrong) answer**

I believe what you are after is a combination of:

- ["Current time" outputs as zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854404/awk-current-time-outputs-as-zero/52854772?noredirect=1#comment92626727_52854772)
- [use awk to print a column, adding a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138569/use-awk-to-print-a-column-adding-a-comma)

So you could do it like,

```
awk '{ print $1,strftime(" %r")}' file | paste -s -d',' > file2
```

Or if it is just awk only,

```
awk '{ printf (NR==1?"":",") $1 OFS strftime(" %r") }' file > file2
```